# Show TabBarView inside CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't figure out how to show a TabBarView inside a CustomScrollView.
I get the error: RenderBox expected but received a child of type RenderSliverList.
The children of TabBarView are of type SliverList.
Any Ideas?

```
child: Scaffold(
        body: SizedBox.expand(
          child: CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(), //details hidden

              //Here is the problem, _screens are of type SliverList
              //I get the error about renderBox expected but received RenderSliverList
              //I need the TabBarView to work here inside the customSCrollView
              //TabBarView(children: _screens).children[0] works but is not what i want,

              TabBarView(children: _screens),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: check `SliverToBoxAdapter`

Comment: already tried but won't work, says that it expects a child of RenderBox but it received a child of type RenderSliverList.

Comment: `child: CustomScrollView(
slivers: [
SliverAppBar(
bottom: TabBar(
tabs: [Text('y0'), Text('t1')],
controller: c,
),
),
SliverToBoxAdapter(
child: SizedBox(
height: 2000,
child: TabBarView(
children: [
Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32), color: Colors.red)),
Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32), color: Colors.orange)),
],
controller: c,
),
),
),
],
),`

Comment: yes it works now by making SizedBoz as child, the only problem is height of the SizedBox at 2000 cannot be changed to fit the content. I tried setting SizedBox.expand but no luck.

Comment: the SizedBox should have a dynamic height otherwise when I scroll it gives an error when going beyond 2000. It must be simple but it gives some Renderflex overflow error when i set the SizedBox to SizedBox.expand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

leaving the answer for some time travellers from future.

Use SliverFillRemaining like below

```
const SliverFillRemaining(
          child: TabBarView(
            children: [
              _CatalogueView(),
              _MyListingsView(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```